# Old text file is downloaded while downloading from server

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, httpclient

I am trying to download a XML file from server to windows store application.

While I am trying downloading the file is getting downloaded.
But when I make changes to the XML file, it is still downloading the old file and my changes are not reflected.
while I access the XML file in chrome ... the changes are there.

After some time it automatically downloads the last updated file... and the issue continues...

Below are two methods I tried to download the file ...

Url: contains the direct file path on server.

```
Using XDocument:

string Xml = XDocument.Load(Url,LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace).ToString();


Using httpClient:

string Xml = String.Empty;

                        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                        {
                            Xml = httpClient.GetStringAsync(Url).Result;
                        }
```

Thanks in advance.
Kindly Help.

Comment: it might be a caching issue.  Try putting an query string on the end of the file name to force the phone to download a new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for feedbacks...

The following code solved my issue:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

  Xml = httpClient.GetStringAsync(URL).Result;
```

it always gets the latest file and do not look into cache.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does sound like a caching issue.  Ideally, you would fix this by having the server send the right caching policy for the file (i.e. not saying that it's valid for longer than it really is).  Failing that, you can change the `httpClient.HttpBaseProtocolFilter.HttpCacheControl.ReadBehavior` to MostRecent, which will always force a check for newer content even if the cached entry appears to be valid.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer... but it was not supported in WP8.1 store app... But it surely was a cache issue...

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid caching is to add a cache-buster param generated from the current time to your url request e.g.

```
my-site/my-xml-file.xml?cachebuster=20140627114601

{year}{month}{day}{hour}{mins}{secs}
```